# Evaluate string to class variable

Tags: c++, string, class

I need to evaluate a string so i can assign a value to a class variable :

Class :

```
class DATACLASS {
public:
    double variable1, variable2, variable3;
};
```

The void init() :

```
void init() 
{
    DATACLASS *d = new DATACLASS;
    std::string ssList[3] = {"variable1", 
                             "variable2", 
                             "variable3"};                        
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
      std::stringstream ss;
      ss << ssList[i];
      //ss.str().c_str() correspond to "variable1", "variable2", "variable3"
      mxArray *array_ptr = mexGetVariable("base", ss.str().c_str());
      double pr = (double)mxGetPr(array_ptr)[0];
      // How to make the same thing here?
      // I would like to have something that would evaluate
      // data->ssList[i] = pr;
      // or more precisely      
      // data->variable1 = pr;
      // but from the ss string like below (but this doesn't work)
      data->ss.str().c_str() = pr;
    }
```

I get this kind of error when trying to do it this way :

```
error C2039: 'ss' : is not a member of 'DATACLASS'
```

Comment: This is called *reflection*, if you want to google for it. Short answer: you can't do that in C++. Use another language, or review your design.

Comment: There's no built-in support for this in C++ like there is in JavaScript. Some people have tried to build reflection frameworks which you might be able to use, but I've never tested any. You'll have to fake it yourself if you really want this sort of thing.

Comment: @AlexandreC. That's good to know there is term for what i'm trying to do. I really didn't know what to look for. It appears I'll have to review my design.

Answer (score 0):

That is not valid C++. What the compiler thinks that you are trying to do is access a member of an instance of `DATACLASS` called `ss` and call some methods on it.

What you are trying to do can be done in reflection, which is not supported in C++. You can half-ass it by using some form of pseudo-reflection model using templates.

Comment: It could be as simple as having a map (list of key-value pairs) if you know all the fields are going to be the same type and then indexing it with `ss.str()`. I suggest that you do not go down the rabbit-hole of trying to use template magic or other pseudo-reflection unless you are fairly confident in your C++ abilities.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you'll reasonably come without a huge amount of effort is something like the following. You could abstract away some things using macros, functions, containers, templates, pointers/references, etc., but this is the basic gist. I wouldn't suggest doing this and committing the time to it unless you have a compelling reason. What is your end goal?

```
class DATACLASS {
public:
    double variable1, variable2, variable3;
};

void init() 
{
    DATACLASS *d = new DATACLASS;
    std::string ssList[3] = {"variable1", 
                             "variable2", 
                             "variable3"};                        
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
      std::stringstream ss;
      ss << ssList[i];
      //ss.str().c_str() correspond to "variable1", "variable2", "variable3"
      mxArray *array_ptr = mexGetVariable("base", ss.str().c_str());
      double pr = (double)mxGetPr(array_ptr)[0];
      if(ss.str() == "variable1")
        data->variable1 = pr;
      else if(ss.str() == "variable2")
        data->variable2 = pr;
      else if(ss.str() == "variable3")
        data->variable3 = pr;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the way it was coded before adding a for loop. Because there could be a huge amount of variable, i'm trying to avoid the use of if else if.

Comment: @m_power I unsderstand. Let me see if I can come up with something else for you, then. It would be easier if the values were always compile-time constants, but then it'd be a less interesting question :)

Comment: @m_power are you trying to avoid `if` statements due to runtime concerns (speed, code size) or development concerns (amount of repetitive typing, risk of mistakes, maintainability nightmare)?

Comment: for simplifying the code and for portability. But at the start, i didn't know that reflection was not possible in cpp. So i might end using `if` statements if there are no alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Are you only reading doubles? You could use pointers to data members for this.

```
    std::map<std::string, double DATACLASS::*> aMembers;
    aMembers["variable1"] = &DATACLASS::variable1;
    aMembers["variable2"] = &DATACLASS::variable2;
    aMembers["variable3"] = &DATACLASS::variable3;

    DATACLASS dc;
    std::string sData = "variable1";
    dc.*aMembers[sData] = 10;
```

In a full solution you would of course have to check that aMembers[sData] exists first. If you need to support multiple data types, you would need to use templates and write some support classes. It should be doable, though.