# c++ evaluating string expression with variables

Tags: c++

I want to do evaluate for example something like:

```
int x=10, y=2;
x=eval('x+(y*10)');
```

Comment: In C++? There is no easy way.

Comment: You basically cannot, not as a generalised solution. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863650/evaluate-string-to-class-variable) for more details and perhaps suggestions for how to solve it for a limited case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i can give you the code which i made, but would like you to try yourself. Here are the steps :

1. replace all the unknowns with their values
2. convert the expression to postfix
3. try to evaluate postfix expression using stacks

Comment: if you are planning to evaluate something like this : "43*x+50-z" x="y/2" y="20" z="10" , i would recommend you to simply add braces to "()" while replacing unknowns.